# loadUserByUsername() method not getting invoked by spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring security and just started learning it. I want to use a custom `User` class, So I'm trying to implement `UserDetailsService` interface and override `loadUserByUsername()`  method to return the custom `User` object. 
 but spring security is not invoking `loadUserByUsername()`,
So user is not getting authenticated, Instead gets redirected to login page. 
I can't figure out what's going wrong
Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/css/**","/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("configureglobal called");

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername called");
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);


return user;

    }
}
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findByName(String name);

}
```

Here is my controller class. Even when a valid username and password is provided, login method is getting called 3 times and `loadUserByUsername()` is not invoked

```
 @Controller
    public class MainController {
        @RequestMapping(value= {"/login"})
        public String login() {
            System.out.println("login called");
            return "login";
        } 

            @RequestMapping(value={"/",/home"})
            public String homeReturner(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {
                System.out.println("home returner called");
                model.addAttribute("name", request.getAttribute("name"));
                return "home";
            }
    }
```

User class

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String username;

    private String password;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String userName) {
        this.username = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Html form in the login page

```
<form action="/signin">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email"> <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"> <button type="submit">Sign in</button><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name=""> <label>Remember me.</label>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name=""><label>Forgot password?</label>
</form>
```

Sign in controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping(path="/signin")
    public String signin() {

            System.out.print("signin called");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

What's going wrong here? Why `loadUserByUsername()` isn't invoked?
Debug Log

```
2018-07-04 21:59:19.249 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2018-07-04 21:59:19.250 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/favicon.ico'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.251 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
2018-07-04 21:59:19.252 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2018-07-04 21:59:19.252 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2018-07-04 21:59:19.252 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2018-07-04 21:59:19.253 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/login'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.254 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7a1d6f3f
2018-07-04 21:59:19.254 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-07-04 21:59:19.257 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-07-04 21:59:19.298 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.298 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.298 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-07-04 21:59:19.298 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@22d63ce1. A new one will be created.
2018-07-04 21:59:19.299 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.300 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.300 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.301 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.301 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2018-07-04 21:59:19.302 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.302 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:19.302 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:19.303 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/home; arg2=/login (property not equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:19.303 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-07-04 21:59:19.303 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.304 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.304 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3793fe54: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FB5BC6CF44B2064132ADF5A75EE463DD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.306 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.306 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.307 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.307 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.308 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2018-07-04 21:59:19.308 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll]
2018-07-04 21:59:19.308 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3793fe54: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FB5BC6CF44B2064132ADF5A75EE463DD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-07-04 21:59:19.309 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7cbce1e2, returned: 1
2018-07-04 21:59:19.310 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2018-07-04 21:59:19.310 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2018-07-04 21:59:19.310 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
login called2018-07-04 21:59:19.320 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7a1d6f3f
2018-07-04 21:59:19.321 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-07-04 21:59:19.326 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-07-04 21:59:19.326 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-07-04 21:59:26.605 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.606 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.607 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2018-07-04 21:59:26.607 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@22d63ce1. A new one will be created.
2018-07-04 21:59:26.607 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.607 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.607 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/logout'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.608 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.608 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/login'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.608 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.609 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:26.609 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: both null (property equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:26.610 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : requestURI: arg1=/home; arg2=/signin (property not equals)
2018-07-04 21:59:26.610 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2018-07-04 21:59:26.610 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.610 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.611 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3793fe54: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FB5BC6CF44B2064132ADF5A75EE463DD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.611 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.612 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.612 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /signin at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.612 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.613 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/login'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.613 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/css/**'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.613 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/signin'; against '/images/**'
2018-07-04 21:59:26.614 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /signin; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-07-04 21:59:26.614 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@3793fe54: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FB5BC6CF44B2064132ADF5A75EE463DD; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-07-04 21:59:26.615 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7cbce1e2, returned: -1
2018-07-04 21:59:26.618 DEBUG 7128 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

Comment: Which endpoint do you hit? What kind of behavior do you expect?

Comment: try to add `@Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }`

Comment: @fg78nc when i try to access /home, its redirecting to login page as expected, but when i submit login form with valid username and password, still its redirecting to login page. i was expecting to hit the home page.

Comment: @fg78nc added the `authenticationManagerBean()`, still not working

Comment: Please see my answer below, as it does not fit into comments nicely

Comment: `@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
 @Autowired
 private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
 ---
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("configureglobal called");
  auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
}

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
---
}`

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and I can see below in logs
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.is_active as is_activ2_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.roles as roles4_0_, user0_.user_name as user_nam5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.user_name=?

1. means loadUserByUserName is searching user with "user_name" in DB.
2. I created userName with userName column in DB
3. when I  select * from user where user_name = '<user_login_name_you_are trying>';
   and it will return user_name = null
   and that's the reason its not autheticating user and its unable to find user in DB.
4. I updated the column with the same value as userName column and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modify as follows.

```
.and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/default") // add page where to navigate after login
                .usernameParameter("username") // make sure your form has correct params
                .passwordParameter("password") // make sure your form has correct params
                .permitAll() // allow access
```

Your controllers :

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                             @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        logger.info("Login(error): {}", error);
        logger.info("Login(logout): {}", logout);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username/password");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("message", "Logged out");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping("/default")
    public String defaultAfterLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Comment: Not working mate, still same result.. Each time the form is submitted , `login()` method is getting invoked 3 times

Comment: updated the question to include html form and sign in controller

Comment: @Arjun try to add `.csrf().disable()` to `http.`

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot 2.0.3

Comment: I enabled debug logging, Its showing `AccessDeniedException`. I'll update the question with debug log.

Comment: 1) add `method="POST"` in your form. 2) You should not return null from `getAuthorities`. Change it to  `@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
       return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    }` 3) add to the bottom of http chain  `.antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('USER'')")` 
or you can just add  `.antMatchers("/**").access("hasAnyRole('USER', 'ANONYMOUS')")` - this will allow ANONYMOUS access as well (this is role you are getting now)

Comment: Actually the issue was that I stored plain text passwords in the db & I didn't use any password encoder during authentication in `configureGlobal()` method, as the passwords were not encoded. I had to use `NoOpPasswordEncoder` during authentication to solve the issue.. It seems, Spring by default expect Bcrypt encoded password during authentication.

Comment: And I used `method="post"` and overridden `getAuthorities()` as you suggested.

Comment: You can add `{noop}` prefix as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by changing the method="get" to method="post" in form.

```
        <form th:action="@{/users/login}" th:method="post" class="login">
            //inputs
            <input type="submit" value="Enter!"/>
        </form>
```